# Solving the system $px+qy+rz=(p^2+q^2+r^2)\cos\theta$, $ax+by+cz=0$, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\sqrt{p^2+q^2+r^2},ap+bq+cr=0$ for $x$, $y$, $z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{align}
px+qy+rz &=(p^2+q^2+r^2)\cos\theta \\[4pt]
ax+by+cz &=0 \\[4pt]
\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} &=\sqrt{p^2+q^2+r^2}
\end{align}$$
$$ap+bq+cr=0$$

How would one express the solution $(x,y,z)$ in terms of real constants $a,b,c,p,q,r$ and $\theta$?

What I have so far:
If I choose z to be a free parameter, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ a & b \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x   \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} (p^2+q^2+r^2)cos(\theta)-rz   \\ -cz \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x   \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} b((p^2+q^2+r^2)cos(\theta)-rz) +cqz  \\ -a((p^2+q^2+r^2)cos(\theta)-rz)-cpz \end{bmatrix}1/(bp-aq)
$$
so
$$\begin{bmatrix} x   \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} b((p^2+q^2+r^2)cos(\theta)-rz) +cqz  \\ -a((p^2+q^2+r^2)cos(\theta)-rz)-cpz \\ z(bp-aq)\end{bmatrix}1/(bp-aq)$$
Then, the rest is a straightforward polynomial in z
$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\sqrt{p^2+q^2+r^2}=\sqrt{(b((p^2+q^2+r^2)cos(\theta)-rz) +cqz)^2/(bp-aq)^2+(-a((p^2+q^2+r^2)cos(\theta)-rz) -cpz)^2/(bp-aq)^2+z^2}$

Comment: What progress have you made? What have you tried?

Comment: @TonyMathew The third equation tells me that (x,y,z) has magnitude √(p^2+q^2+r^2). I can modify the first two equations into a 2x2 matrix multiplied by a 2x1 column vector = another 2x1 column vector. I can achieve this by letting one of the variables x,y, or z be a free parameter and expressing the other two variables in terms of the free parameter. Solving the 2x2 matrix equation would tell me the correct direction of my desired (x,y,z) vector, and the third quation would tell me the magnitude of my desired vector. Proceeding with this idea hasn't worked out for me, though

Comment: The line in space containing my desired vector would be expressed in terms of a free parameter. I could let z be the free parameter, for instance. After taking the 2x2 matrix's inverse and solving for the line containing (x,y,z), I could then intersect this line with a sphere of radius √(p^2+q^2+r^2) centered at the origin and the two solutions would be the possible solutions (x,y,z).

Comment: The system is homogeneous so it's enough to solve it for $\|(p,q,r)\|=\|(a,b,c)\|=\|(x,y,z)\|=1$. Then you need to find a vector orthogonal to a given vector, having a given angle with another vector.

Comment: As you say, the last equation is a straightforward polynomial in $z$, specifically a quadratic. So you could solve for $z$, plug the expression into your equations for $x,y$ and get two solutions in terms of the constants. Is the problem that this method is tedious/results in ugly expressions?

Comment: @TonyMathew precisely. I'm having a hard time doing it by hand, and all of the online calculators I've tried have given up on it

Comment: @TonyMathew my intuition is that the column vector (x,y,z) can be expressed as a 3x3 rotation matrix times the column vector (p,q,r). Thus, the final expression is possibly not so ugly

Comment: Re-phrased ... given vectors $(a,b,c)$ and $(p,q,r)$, and angle $\theta$, find vector $(x,y,z)$ that is: perpendicular to $(a,b,c)$ with angle $\theta$  between $(p,q,r)$ and $(x,y,z)$.  Whether this exists will be determined by the angle between $(a,b,c)$ and $(p,q,r)$.

Comment: @GEdgar (a,b,c) and (p,q,r) are orthogonal. And yes; I originally formulated this problem as a geometry problem involving these vectors

Comment: If you want $(a,b,c)$ and $(p,q,r)$ to be orthogonal, you should put that in the statement of the problem.  That makes it much easier!  Then the plane through the origin perpendicular to $(a,b,c)$ contains the point $(p,q,r)$. Rotate $(p,q,r)$ about axis $(a,b,c)$ through angle $\theta$; the result is $(x,y,z)$.  There are two drections you could rotate; so there are usually two answers.

Comment: @GEdgar is there an existing formula that I can use to come up with a 3x3 rotation matrix in terms of $p,q,r,a,b,c $ and $\theta$? My idea is that each of the 2 possible 3x3 rotation matrices would correspond to one of the 2 solutions (rotating in one direction versus the opposite direction)

Comment: Rotate in $3$-space to reduce to the case $(a,b,c) = (R,0,0), (p,q,r) = (0,R,0)$, solve that case explicitly $(x,y,z) = (0,R\cos\theta,\pm R\sin\theta)$ then rotate back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the algebra becomes messy, my method is to repeatedly define groups of constants as new constants. In your problem, you only care about $x,y,z$: you don't need to worry about the interactions of the remaining constants until the end where you express the final solution in terms of them. So for example, you could define common constant expressions in your final equation as such
$$d=\sqrt{(b(d^2 cos(\theta)-rz) +cqz)^2/e +(-a(d^2 cos(\theta)-rz) -cpz)^2/e+z^2} \\
d = ||(p,q,r)|| = \sqrt{p^2+q^2+r^2}, \quad e = (bp-aq)^2 $$

But this is still ugly, so if you square both sides, expand the $b()$ and $a()$ then define some more, you get this relatively cleaner equation.

$$f_1 = (f_2 z + f_3)^2 +(f_4 z + f_5)^2 + e z^2 \\
f_1 = d^2e, \quad f_2 = cq - br, \quad f_3 = bd^2 cos(\theta), \quad f_4 = a r -cp, \quad f_5 = -a d^2 cos(\theta)$$

Hopefully the $f$ equation is now clean enough for you to solve for $z$ in terms of $f$'s and $e$. Then you could substitute for $z$ in your $x,y$ equations, then substitute the $f$'s, then $d,e$. I agree that the final solution will still be ugly, but maybe it won't be as hard for you to get there now.

---

Alternative thoughts in case they lead to a simpler solution approach:

Interpreting the algebraic system of equations as vector constraints, you want to solve for $\vec{X}$ given $\vec{P}, \vec{A}, \theta$ in the following.
$$\vec{P} \cdot \vec{X} = ||P||^2 \cos \theta \\
\vec{A} \cdot \vec{X} = 0 \\
||X|| = ||P||$$

Geometrically, you want to find a vector with same magnitude as $\vec{P}$ but forming an angle of $\theta$ with it and is also perpendicular to $\vec{A}$. So in line with your comment, you would want to find something like,
$$\vec{X} = M \vec{P}$$

where $M$ is a rotation matrix that rotates by $\theta$ in a rotational plane containing $\vec{A}$ such that the resulting vector is in the plane normal to $\vec{A}$.

Comment: I'll use exactly those substitutions and get my 2 solutions. After I do so, can I use the resulting solutions to then derive the rotation matrix M in terms of all of the constants? My guess is I can, but it's not immediately obvious to me how I'd come up with the rotation matrix, whether it be with or without first having my 2 solutions

Comment: Also, would it be the case that one solution corresponds to an M that rotates by theta, while the other solution corresponds to an M that rotates by negative theta?

Comment: I'm aware that a general 3x3 rotation matrix can be expressed in terms of yaw, pitch and roll. Is there not a way to express a general rotation matrix in terms of the components of the starting vector, the components of a vector along the axis of rotation orthogonal to the starting vector, and the angle of rotation? It seems to me that such a formula ought to exist, and if it exists then I could make all of this much easier by using the formula

Answer (score 0):

Can someone tell me if the following solution is correct
$$
\begin{bmatrix} cos(\theta) & -csin(\theta)/d & bsin(\theta)/d \\\ csin(\theta)/d & cos(\theta) & -asin(\theta)/d  \\\ -bsin(\theta)/d & asin(\theta)/d & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} p  \\\ q \\\ r\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $d=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$